# Creating and removing <div> element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dom-manipulation

```
function labelOnClick () {
    function makeDivId(id) {
        return id + "_div";
    };

    var div = this.getElementById(makeDivId(this.id));

    if (div) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    } else {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "welcome";
        div.id = makeDivId(this.id);

        this.appendChild(div);
    }
}




<label id="1" onclick="labelOnClick()" > BROWSER </label>
<label id="2" onclick="labelOnClick()"> GAMING CONSOLE </label>
```

In the above example, I'm trying to create a `div` element when a label is clicked and remove the created `div` element when the label is clicked again, but it's not working.

Comment: You had two issues, the first problem is that `getElementById` is a method of `document`, not `HTMLElement`.

The second is incorrect use of the this keyword.  Using inline events, you need to pass it as a argument, as `this` will refer to the `window`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

- When assigning event handlers inline (`label onclick="..."`) inside the event handler function `this` will point to the global object (`window`). You can pass `this` as an argument to the function.
- Certain browsers will fail when assigning the result of `getElementById()` to a variable if no element is found (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Something like this would work:

```
<script>
function labelOnClick (me) {
    var makeDivId=function (id) {
        return id + "_div";
    };
    var div;

    if (document.getElementById(makeDivId(me.id))) {
        div=document.getElementById(makeDivId(me.id));
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    } else {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "welcome";
        div.id = makeDivId(me.id);

        me.appendChild(div);
    }
}
</script>

<label id="1" onclick="labelOnClick(this)" > BROWSER </label>
<label id="2" onclick="labelOnClick(this)"> GAMING CONSOLE </label>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XHV7X/1/)

Comment: @thuk If you are satisfied with any of the answers here, you can accept one by clicking the tickmark on the left of the answer.

Comment: the above code is not running on my system. what may be the problem.

Comment: @thuk Please describe `not running` and `my system`. Be sure to check out my jsFiddle as well.

Comment: when i copy the above code to notepad and run in googlechrome it is not running. it is running in jsfiddle.et........

Comment: @thuk Hm yes, @circusbred seems to be right. Change `me.getElementById` to `document.getElementById`. Used jQuery for too long for DOM traversal and modifications :).

Comment: ya. now it is working fine..... thanks. but now i need to extend this as when i click a label another label should be created under this and when that label is clicked another label and so on... and one main thing if the parent of the label is clicked all the label below that created should be removed.... i am doing that .. any suggestion........

Comment: @thuk Well, you might be better off using a library like jQuery for this, but based on this working example, I guess it should be doable. If you run into problems open a separate question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to not add the div using the javascript, but to change the div tag's visibility style property on click..

```
function labelOnClick () {
    function makeDivId(id) {
        return id + "_div";
    };

    //var div = this.getElementById(makeDivId(this.id));

    if (document.getElementById("divID").style.visibility == "visible") {
        document.getElementById("divID").style.visibility = "hidden";          
    } else {
        document.getElementById("divID").style.visibility = "hidden";  
    }
}

    <label id="1" onclick="labelOnClick()" > BROWSER </label>
    <label id="2" onclick="labelOnClick()"> GAMING CONSOLE </label>
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the div to the markup as well. I suspect this won't actually do what the OP wants (displaying the div attached to the right label).

Comment: True, the div should be added to the markup, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the "this" keyword in place of "document", which does not work since "this" is pointing to the labelOnClick function.

```
function labelOnClick(e)
{
    function makeDivId(id)
    {
        return id + "_div";
    };

    var div = document.getElementById(makeDivId(this.id));

    if (div)
    {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
    else
    {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "welcome";
        div.id = makeDivId(this.id);

        var element = e.target;
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(div, element.nextSibling);
    }
}


<label id="1" onclick="labelOnClick(event)" > BROWSER </label>
<label id="2" onclick="labelOnClick(event)"> GAMING CONSOLE </label>
```

I wrote this assuming you are using something that supports the "target" property of the event object (e.g. not internet explorer).  If you need cross browser support, you can do it manually or use a framework like jQuery or Prototype.

The way the original code was written, I assumed that you wanted a div per label and I guessed at the positioning (immediately following the label).