# Javascript delete div Element

Tags: javascript, html, stopwatch

I am implementing a Stopwatch in JavaScript.

I want to delete additional div elements when pushing a `clear` button. I added function `cc();`, but `function cc()` doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Javascript:

```
a = 0;
myButton = 0;

function myWatch(flug) {
  if(myButton == 0) {
    Start = new Date();
    myButton = 1;
    document.myForm.myFormButton.value = "Stop!";
    myInterval = setInterval("myWatch(1)", 1);
  } else {
    if(flug == 0) {
      myButton = 0;
      document.myForm.myFormButton.value = "Start";
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
    Stop = new Date();
    T = Stop.getTime() - Start.getTime();
    H = Math.floor(T / (60 * 60 * 1000));
    T = T - (H * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    M = Math.floor(T / (60 * 1000));
    T = T - (M * 60 * 1000);
    S = Math.floor(T / 1000);
    Ms = T % 1000;
    document.myForm.myClick.value = H + ":" + M + ":" + S + ":" + Ms;
  }
}
b = 0;

function stop() {
  b++;
  stopa();
}

function stopa() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.id = pos;
  var objBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")
    .item(0);
  objBody.appendChild(element);
  rap = "";
  rap = "rap" + b + "=" + H + ":" + M + ":" + S + ":" + Ms;
  element.innerHTML = rap;
}

function cc() {
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="#">
  <input type="text" size="20" name="myClick">
  <input type="button" value="Start" name="myFormButton" onclick="myWatch(0)" />
  <input type="button" value="Rap" name="Rap" onclick="stop()">
  <input type="button" value="clear" name="clear" onclick="cc()">
</form>
<h3>
  <div id="pos">
  </div>
</h3>
```

Comment: `element` is a _local_ variable in your `stopa` function - `cc` does not know any variable of that name. Looks like you are missing knowledge of absolute JS basics ... maybe you should work through a few tutorials first?

Comment: You need to pass the element's reference to the cc function, or make element a global var.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [creating and removing div element in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152132/creating-and-removing-div-element-in-javascript) and [JavaScript: remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the context explicitly as parameter on the `cc()` function.

js

```
function cc(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

html

```
<input type="button" value="clear" name="clear" onclick="cc(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up your Console. It's found in most major browsers and will help you loads with JS development.

For example, [if you look at your code exactly as is](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/MMywX/), you get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
```

As several have said, it's [a variable scope issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope). There's a few easy fixes, the easiest being simply making `element` have a larger scope - that is, define it outside of your functions first.

```
var element = null;
```

and then in `stopa`, don't use `var` because it'll make a new, local variable instead of using the global one.

```
element = document.createElement('div');
```

The next problem you'll notice is that `element` in `cc` still doesn't refer to the correct element - this is because in the following line, `pos` is not defined.

```
element.id = pos;
```

Again, take a look at the Console (now more specifically at the HTML section than the JS, but it's in the same developer options). You'll notice the created element's ID is `[object HTMLDivElement]` - not "pos". I'd recommend not even worrying about giving them `id`s, you have a div with id `pos` already in your HTML, simply append your results to that instead of the `body`.

```
objBody = document.getElementById("pos");
```

Then when you clear, clear all children from `pos` (you'll also want to clear the text box I'm sure, so here ya go)

```
while (objBody.hasChildNodes()) {
  objBody.removeChild(objBody.lastChild);
}
document.myForm.myClick.value = "";
```

Notice now we no longer need `element` to be global, because it's only referenced in one function - it can be local to that function. However, `objBody` is now referenced in `stopa` and `cc`, so we'll make it global as we did with `element` and simply ensure all future references to it don't include `var`.

```
var element = null;
```

Add some error checking (clearing before you click Start causes errors, for example) and you're good to go!

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/MMywX/1/

Answer (score 0):

The function `cc` has no idea what 'element' is.  The easiest way to fix this is to use jquery.  When you delete the div, do something like

```
$('#pos').remove()
```

This finds the div with id 'pos' and removes it.  You may need to pass the id of the div to cc if it's not just 'pos'.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers supports **remove()** method on the element. You don't need to use external libraries as jQuery or long code. It's simple as :

```
var x = document.getElementById("myElement");
x.remove();
```

Working exemple here -> https://jsfiddle.net/tmj3p7t5/